# Proving $k[x,y]/(x^p + y^p - a)$ is integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In the wikipedia article for [geometrically regular rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrically_regular_ring) they mention that if $k$ is field of characteristic $p$ and $a \in k$ is an element that isn't a $p$th power then the curve given by $x^p + y^p = a$ has every point being regular but isn't geometrically regular. The article by Zariski they cite uses the fact that $k[x,y]/(x^p + y^p - a)$ gives a normal curve, hence is regular at each point. However, I can't figure out how to prove $k[x,y]/(x^p + y^p - a)$ is integrally closed. I'm pretty sure it's not a UFD, and my attempts to brute force show it with polynomials have gotten stuck. What's a way I can show this?

Comment: If $p\ne 2$ and $a\not \in k^p$ then $k[x,y]/(x^p+y^p-a)=k[x+y,x-y]/((x+y)^p-a)\cong k[s,t]/(s^p-a)=K[t]$ where $K=k[s]/(s^p-a)$ is a field.

Comment: Thanks! So if $p=2$ the issue is that $x+y = x-y$, right? Also is it no longer integrally closed in that case?

Comment: If $p=2$ then $k[x,y]/(x^p+y^p-a)=k[x+y,x]/((x+y)^p-a) \cong k[s,x]/(s^p-a)=K[x]$ so it is the same